# Is it safe to create a class based on vector/list of its instances?

Tags: c++, list, vector, stl, std

```
class CTest : public std::vector<CTest*>
{
      // ...
};
```

Is it safe to do like this? Which should i use, vector or list if yes?

Comment: In this world most of questions already have an answer. Somewhere

Comment: Thats why theres a search box

Comment: Didn't know that. Damn. Maybe i am the first one who named such question correct, because i didn't found an answer. It is not so hard to just answer this question.

Comment: This isn't _entirely_ redundant: it could be that the use of `CTest` in the inheritance creates additional problems.  I don't think that it does, although the usual business of "who owns these pointers?" applies.